# Implementing facebook login in samsung smart tv apps

Tags: facebook, samsung-smart-tv

I want to implement facebook login and sharing image feature of facebook in my samsung smart tv app.
Does any one have any idea of how to implement this in samsung smart tv apps

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the pop ups are blocked on smart TV's. 
I'm using LG's emulator to create an app with facebook login abilities. To get around the problem of the facebook login pop up I've had to use a modal window that calls facebooks full screen login page. Then do a callback to your app.

:)

Comment: well  it will work on samsung smart tv the same way can you give me some more idea about it  ?